# Averaging win/loss data by day in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

There's been similar questions answered here but I've been unable to apply those tips to my scenario. I keep data on gambling wins and loses. I want to calculate averages based on the day of the week. I should point out my spreadsheet includes dates with no data (for a reason). The formula I've been trying use for this is =AVERAGE(IF(C2:C19="Mon",B2:B19)). I've included a [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IK5KyC4Ib3H5zr4iv8l70p9FY47s-12M_8N1g00hd4M/edit?usp=sharing). My knowledge of spreadsheets is severely limited. I know just enough to get in trouble. Thanks in advance for any help, this is my first question on the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=query(A2:B,"select dayOfWeek(A), avg(B) where not A is null group by dayOfWeek(A) label dayOfWeek(A) 'Day', avg(B) 'Average by Day' format dayOfWeek(A) 'dddd' ")
```

This will generate all the results in one go.

Comment: Nicely done! If I could I'd buy you and your friends a round of beers but I guess saying thanks will have to do. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).